# Invalid Access Token format Twitter4j 2.2.6

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

This is my stack trace, and I can't figure out whats wrong!

```
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format.
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at twitter4j.auth.AccessToken.<init>(AccessToken.java:50)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at com.project.p.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:21)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at com.project.p.activities.Activity$4.onClick(Activity.java:313)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-30 12:26:50.494: E/AndroidRuntime(19465):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's pointing me to this code

```
public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

    String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
    String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
            Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

    try {
        twitter.getAccountSettings();
        return true;
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

specifically the line

```
AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
```

It was all working fine when I used the twitter4j 2.1.1 but I had to update for other reasons

Comment: Please update if you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking `OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN` and `OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET` from prefs, go to your application page in Twitter and create your access token which you can do with a button on the bottom of the ***Details*** tab and it will give you the parameters you need.

Use those instead of token and secret strings in your code.

I do not know if this is the healthiest way to solve this problem since we are hard coding these values, but it solved my problem for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> twitter.getAccountSettings();

to

> twitter.verifyCredentials();

Worked for me..

[Edit]

Also capture the exception when creating the AccessToken with empty token and secret.